# Writing a basic java shell or GUI on a kernel

Tags: java, shell, user-interface, operating-system, kernel

As a hobby I have been writing a shell in java. It's very basic, it include the creation, deletion, reading of files through a command line or through a desktop-like environment if a plugin is installed (which I also wrote).

Now my question is a very complicated one, but I hope someone can point me to the right direction.

- Is there a layer or an operating system out there that has java
  support, so I can run my java application on top of it, to serve as a
  shell? Something minimal?

I don't fully understand the library inheritance in java to its full extent yet, and I'm not sure if AWT and swing applications are something that is built for the major OSs out there.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I just want to learn here, and I don't fully understand the full details of the layers underneath my java program.

Comment: Android maybe? Its userland is almost completely java-based.

Comment: I'd suggest a barebones Debian or Fedora install of Linux. It gives you JVM support, great performance, and no preexisting GUI to displace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) 2 examples where Java is supported at the operating system level

- Sun had a bare-metal operating system called JavaOS which is no longer available.  I don't recall the exact details but I think that the target architecture was some kind of embedded processor.
- There is an open source bare-metal Java operating system called [JNode](http://jnode.org) that runs on x86.  It already has a command shell (the "bjorne" shell) and a primitive GUI.

The bad news with JNode is that it doesn't have a working "isolates" implementation, so it is impossible to stop a buggy applications from bringing the operating system to its knees.  This has become a roadblock to progress ... especially since a viable isolates implementation probably would require a redesign of the system architecture to support a separate address space for each isolate.

Comment: Imitating Java syntax but not having the VM sounds like a freak of nature to me. Doesn't this defeat the whole purpose of Java being a platform-independent language?

Comment: @icepack - on the contrary.  JNode is (conceptually) a Java virtual machine that is also the operating system.  It runs platform independent bytecode files more or less faithfully.  The difficulty is that JNode effectively provides just one JVM instance for everything, and running multiple conventional Java apps in one JVM is problematic.

Comment: You're including the VM in the language. The VM is the mediator and interface of Java to the OS but not part of the language. Whatever goes inside the VM doesn't really matter (it might abstract the OS or implement it, like in your example), it's a black box as far as Java developer concerned.

Comment: @icepack - I don't understand what you are getting at.  If you are arguing that a JVM has to have an operating system underneath it to qualify as a JVM, please provide an authoritative reference for that definition of JVM.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying. I am saying that JVM may have an OS beneath it or the OS may be internal to it. That doesn't matter from Java developer perspective

Comment: @icepack - I don't disagree with that.  What is your point?  Note I've already said that JNode **is** a JVM (modulo that we probably shouldn't call it one for trademark reason) ... and it is also an operating system.

Comment: My point is that **"There are (at least) 2 examples where Java is supported at the operating system level"** is incorrect. Java is supported at JVM level, which may or may not be also an operating system - this is irrelevant for Java itself.

Comment: Whatever.  If all you are doing is hair-splitting over what "Java is supported at the operating system level" *means* (to you), then this discussion is pointless.

Comment: So Java is also supported on hardware and transistor and atomic level, following your logic. After all, these entities are essential for Java to run. JVM in your example must have 2 layers at least - one to interface the HW (the actual OS) and second one to provide the interfaces required for the Java language. This second layer is what distinguishes managed language from non-managed. It really doesn't matter if the first layer is part of JVM or not for that matter since it's not relevant to Java itself.

Comment: JNode does not work the way you imagine, but I don't have the time to explain it adequately.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't interact directly with the OS, instead it uses the Java VM that serves as a mediator between the Java app and the hosting OS. Having this VM allows Java apps to be portable since it abstracts away the OS specifics. Java VM implementations differ for different OSs but that's probably not something you should be worrying about; the VM is available and distributed for most major OSs, just download and install the one for yours from http://www.java.com. After that you're free to go with your app.